# Is there way to Crop Image in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I added images into sheet via `Insert > Image > Image over cells`

But I can't find any tool or Add-on to crop it.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You may insert the picture use : Insert > Drawing > Image the pick the picture you need and crop the pic as you want

Comment: This actually works!. Hate when people downvote without actually checking the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

OR:  Copy the image desired to be cropped into Google Docs, utilize the Cropping tool in the toolbar and edit.  (Copy) the newly cropped image and (Paste) it into Google Sheets.  I just tested it and it works.  june